# scipy.optimize.minimize : compute hessian and gradient together

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, optimization, scipy

The scipy.optimize.minimize function implements basically the equivalent to MATLAB's 'fminunc' function for finding local minima of functions.

In scipy, functions for the gradient and Hessian are separate.

```
res = minimize(rosen, x0, method='Newton-CG',
...                jac=rosen_der, hess=rosen_hess,
...                options={'xtol': 1e-30, 'disp': True})
```

However, I have a function whose Hessian and gradient share quite a few computations and I'd like to compute the Hessian and gradient together, for efficiency. In fminunc, the objective function can be written to return multiple values, i.e:

```
function [ q, grad, Hessian ] = rosen(x)
```

Is there a good way to pass in a function to scipy.optimize.minimize that can compute these elements together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go for a caching solution, but first numpy arrays are not hashable, and second you only need to cache a few values depending on whether the algorithm goes back and forth a lot on `x`. If the algorithm only moves from one point to the next, you can cache only the last computed point in this way, with your `f_hes` and `f_jac` being just lambda interfaces to a longer function computing both:

```
import numpy as np

# I choose the example f(x,y) = x**2 + y**2, with x,y the 1st and 2nd element of x below:
def f(x):
    return x[0]**2+x[1]**2

def f_jac_hess(x):
    if all(x==f_jac_hess.lastx):
        print('fetch cached value')
        return f_jac_hess.lastf
    print('new elaboration')
    res = array([2*x[0],2*x[1]]),array([[2,0],[0,2]])

    f_jac_hess.lastx = x
    f_jac_hess.lastf = res

    return res

f_jac_hess.lastx = np.empty((2,)) * np.nan

f_jac = lambda x : f_jac_hess(x)[0]
f_hes = lambda x : f_jac_hess(x)[1]
```

Now the second call would cache the saved value:

```
>>> f_jac([3,2])
new elaboration
Out: [6, 4]
>>> f_hes([3,2])
fetch cached value
Out: [[2, 0], [0, 2]]
```

You then call it as:

```
minimize(f,array([1,2]),method='Newton-CG',jac = f_jac, hess= f_hes, options={'xtol': 1e-30, 'disp': True})
```

Comment: Thanks, I suspected the soln would involve some sort of global variables. Seems like it would be useful and fairly simple to re-write the _minimize_trust_ncg() function to take in a function generator for all three functions, like fminunc does.