# How to compute objective, gradient and hessian within one function and pass it to scipy.optimize.minimize?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

According to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), if `jac` is a Boolean and `True`, then the objective
function `fun` is assumed to return `(f, grad)`, i.e. the objective value
and the gradient. This is useful to avoid duplicated computations
of terms arising in both the objective and the gradient.

Now I was wondering whether there is an similar option or way to achieve
the same for the hessian `hess` such that objective function can return
a tuple `(f, grad, hess)`, where `hess` is the hessian matrix?

Here's a MWE:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def obj_and_grad_and_hess(x):
    obj = np.exp(x) * x**2
    grad = obj + 2*np.exp(x)*x
    hess = obj + 4*np.exp(x)*(x) + 2*np.exp(x)
    return obj, grad, hess

# res = minimize(obj_and_grad_and_hess, x0=[1.0], jac=True, hess=True)
```

This question is
similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003543/scipy-optimize-minimize-compute-hessian-and-gradient-together), where the
jacobian function can return the jacobian and the hessian.

Comment: I don't understand why you are asking this. You literally linked to the current documentation for minimize which shows all the options the function supports. The lack of what you are asking for is obvious (also your assumption about improved performance is probably wrong because most algorithms don't require recalculation of the Hessian at every search step)

Comment: I am aware that this option is lacking. That's the reason why I asked whether
there's another way to implement it. And with all due respect, I think you
are wrong with your statement with respect to the performance.

Comment: If you don't trust the docs to be complete, you read the `[source]`  to test it.

Answer (score 3):

Under the hood, scipy.optimize.minimize uses the [`MemoizeJac`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/8647ee9246cc561996c02f6ec535cae3aa69b225/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L55)
decorator to handle the `jac=True` case. The decorator caches the function's return values `f` and `grad` each time it is called. By inheriting from this class, you can implement a `MemoizeJacHess` decorator in the same vein:

```
from scipy.optimize.optimize import MemoizeJac

class MemoizeJacHess(MemoizeJac):
    """ Decorator that caches the return vales of a function returning
        (fun, grad, hess) each time it is called. """

    def __init__(self, fun):
        super().__init__(fun)
        self.hess = None

    def _compute_if_needed(self, x, *args):
        if not np.all(x == self.x) or self._value is None or self.jac is None or self.hess is None:
            self.x = np.asarray(x).copy()
            self._value, self.jac, self.hess = self.fun(x, *args)

    def hessian(self, x, *args):
        self._compute_if_needed(x, *args)
        return self.hess
```

However, since there is no support for a `hess=True` option yet, you have to
use it like this:

```py
obj = MemoizeJacHess(obj_and_grad_and_hess)
grad = obj.derivative
hess = obj.hessian

res = minimize(obj, x0=[1.0], jac=grad, hess=hess)
```